# Unable to load the Google Search page in your browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a simple code to launch the `Firefox` browser and load the google page but it launched the browser but failed to load the google page I am using `selenium-java-2.33.0` and `firefox 35.0` version

```
package com.webdriver.chapter1;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class navigateToAUrl {
public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

}
}
```

What is causing the problem?

Comment: Manually i can able to access google.com. Failed to load i mean blank address bar without any url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incompatible webdriver jars for the firefox version you use.
Use the latest jars which is version 2.44 (at this time of posting this answer).

Download from here http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ & replace the old ones with the new jar. It should work fine.